# Generating pseudodata as in "Elements of Statistical Learning"

Tags: machine-learning, linear-model

I am trying to implement a Simulation from the book "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie et al.

My Problem is that I don't understand how to generate the pseudodata as they did. 
The book says

> For each of N = 100 Samples, we generated p standard Gaussian features X with pairwise correlation 0.2. The outcome Y was generated according to a linear model* $$Y = \sum_{j=1}^p X_j  \beta_j + \sigma \epsilon,$$ *where $\epsilon$ was generated from a Standard Gaussian Distribution. For each dataset, the set of coefficients $\beta_j$ were also generated from a Standard Gaussian Distribution. We investigated p = 20, 100 and 1000. The standard deviation $ \sigma $ was chosen in each case so that the signal-to-noise-ratio $Var[E(Y|X)]/ \sigma ^2 $equaled 2.

So, what I managed to generate so far are the Xs, the $\epsilon$ and the $\beta$s.

I don't get how I'm meant to generate Y without knowing $\sigma$ and according to the description of $\sigma$, I need Y to compute it.

Can someone please help me? What am I not understanding here?? 
Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Math mode is accessed by placing $\TeX$ between dollar sign delimiters or double dollar signs to set off an equation on its own line.  I edited part of your post to illustrate.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the Information, looks much better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The standard deviation sigma was chosen in each case so that the signal-to-noise-ratio $Var(E[Y|X]) / \sigma^2$ equaled 2.

Because $\epsilon$ has mean 0, we know that:

$$E[Y \mid X] = \sum_{j=1}^p X_j \beta_j = \beta^T X$$

So, using the $X$ and $\beta$ you generated, calculate the variance of $E[Y \mid X]$ and divide it by 2 to obtain $\sigma^2$.

Clarification: this should be done by treating $X$ as a random variable, not by working with samples. $E[Y \mid X]$ is a linear combination of Gaussian random variables so, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Matrix_notation_for_the_variance_of_a_linear_combination) and by whuber in the comments below:

$$Var(E[Y \mid X]) = \beta^T C \beta$$

where $C$ is the covariance matrix of $X$

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm still not entirely sure what you mean:  "calculate $E(Y|X)$ for each value of $X$"  - do you rather mean to compute $E(Y_i|X)= \sum_{j=1}^{p} X_{ij}b_j$ (for i = 1,...,100) or do you mean something like $E(Y|X_?)$ ?

Comment: The expression "$\operatorname{Var}(E[Y\mid X])$" is a variance taken with respect to the distribution of the *random variable* $X$.  Thus, a prescription to use only a particular realization of $X$ would be at best an approximation to what was intended.  Instead, once the $\beta_j$ have been generated, you need to work out this variance mathematically and use *that* value to determine $\sigma^2$.  That's straightforward to do using the rules for computing variances and the fact that you know the variance-covariance matrix of $X$.

Comment: @whuber so this is what I get mathematically and then try to implement in R:
 `beta = data.frame(rnorm(20))

for (i in 1:20){
    for (j in 1:20){
 if (i != j){
         a=sum(beta[i,1]^2)+0.2*sum(beta[i,1]*beta[j,1]);}}}` 
Is that any good? 
Your help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: No amount of code is going to make up for the difference between $X$ as a *random variable,* which is the interpretation demanded by the notation in the quotation, and $X$ as a realization of random values, which is what you are doing.

Comment: @whuber I didn't use any realizations of $X$ this time, only of $\beta$. I used 0.2 for the covariances of the $X$-pairs and 1 for the Variance of each $X$. Please correct me if that's not what you intended to explain earlier?

Comment: I see; thanks for correcting me.  I think I can make out portions of the necessary matrix multiplication, but you don't seem to be summing the results as you should. Since for $\beta=(\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_p)^\prime$, $$\operatorname{Var}(E[Y\mid X])=\beta^\prime \operatorname{Var}(X)\beta,$$ a convenient calculation of $\sigma^2$ is `beta <- rnorm(20); rho <- 0.2; beta %*% (diag(1-rho, p) + matrix(rho, p, p)) %*% beta / 2`.  Another way that's computationally fast (but perhaps not so clearly related to the formula) is `((1-rho)*sum(beta^2) + rho*sum(beta)^2) / 2`.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your input, I simply forgot to consider the option of Matrix multiplication (that's why I tried the loops). 
I have one more question: I generated the $X$s with  `mvrnorm` because with `rnorm` the correlations wouldn't play a role. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Yes, `mvrnorm` will work.